# How to print error in Swift code?

Tags: swift, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
     func marseJSON(Person: String)
{


    let jsonData1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "\(label2)")!) as NSData!

    var error : NSError?
    let ReadableJSON1 = JSON ( data:jsonData1, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error )

  //  print(error)

   LabelText1.text = "There is a problem with the qr code! or simply error"
```

I have a function which reads a QR code, the problem is that this QR code should be always a link from my server. Would you please show me how can I display an error message into the  LabelText1.text if the user does not scan the right QR code for my server.
I have tried by myself but I am new in swift and it seems that the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try UIAlertController:

```
   if (error != nil){

   let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert) //you can change message to whatever you want.
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
   myAlert.addAction(okAction)
   self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   return
       }
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming you are using Swift 3)

Use `do { ... } catch { ... }`:

```
do {
    let ReadableJSON1 = try JSON (data:jsonData1, options:.mutableContainers)
    // everything is ok, proceed
} catch {
    print(error)        
    LabelText1.text = "There is a problem with the qr code! or simply error"
}
```